# Null value causing issue saving to the database

Tags: c#, webforms

I am trying to convert a text box into a decimal when I try this method it says that inpurt string was not in correct format what is the best way around this.

```
 _record.houseHoldArrearsAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(txtArrearsAmount.Text)
```

I persume it is because text is "" null and and 0.00 hence it falls over

The compiler run time is causing an exception

The input is blank if the user has not entered a value as of yet

Comment: so add a check on the content of the box before passing it as argiment...what's the actual issue?

Comment: Please add the full error output for the exception. Also, I think you may have meant to tag this as C#.

Comment: can i not use the ? flag in this case to proivde a value it should be if null

Comment: And what is the "input"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that the text is always going to be a number you can still use Convert but check that the string isn't empty first:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtArrearsAmount.Text))
{
    _record.houseHoldArrearsAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(txtArrearsAmount.Text);
}
```

Obviously this won't update the `houseHoldArrearsAmount` if it's not a numeric value. What you do in this case depends on your business model. You might want to set it to 0 or you might want to leave it with the old value and report and error.

Alternatively, if the input could be any string, you can use `Decimal.TryParse` to convert the string to a number.

```
decimal result;
if (decimal.TryParse(txtArrearsAmount.Text, out result))
{
    _record.houseHoldArrearsAmount = result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the null coalescing operator (as your suggested in comments), as the string value of the textbox won't be null, it will be an empty string.

You could do the following:

```
_record.householdArrearsAmount = 
       (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtArrearsAmount.Text) ? 0 : 
          Convert.ToDecimal(txtArrearsAmount.Text));
```

Comment: IsNullOrWhitespace doest not appear to be standard .net is this a function you have in a helper file

Comment: Needed a capital S on space, sorry: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use "TryParse" funtion.

```
decimal householdArrearsAmount  = decimal.Zero;
decimal.TryParse(txtArrearsAmount.Text, out householdArrearsAmount);
_record.householdArrearsAmount = householdArrearsAmount;
```